# Grep in partial matching in R

Tags: r, regex

I can match my input `ex` with vector `str` with following code

here "exp" matches with `str`

```
str <- c("Regular", "expression", "examples of R language")    
x <- grep("exp",str,value=F)
```

But Instead I want to match  "expression" with `str` like this

Input is "expression" and it should match str "exp" in below example

```
str <- c("Regular", "exp", "examples of R language")`
x <- grep("expression",str,value=F) 
x

#exp
```

My x = "expression" should match with str "exp"and result should give "exp"

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

We need to extract the substring.  In `base R`, this can be done with `regexpr/regmatches`

```
regmatches(str, regexpr("exp", str))
#[1] "exp"
```

---

Or using `stringr/stringi`

```
library(stringr)
na.omit(str_extract(str, 'exp'))
#[1] "exp"
```

---

Using `grep` we can find whether there is a partical match or not.  It returns the numeric index of the element or a logical vector (by using `grepl`).  With `value = TRUE`, it returns the element that is matched and not the partial substring

Comment: thanks for taking time to reply but your answer does not satisfy my requirement. I know how to match "exp" with "expression" and I have written that in code. I want to match "expression" to "exp". Please go through the description. Thanks again.

Comment: @SubharanjanSahoo  Well, your description was confusing bcz you used `"exp" somewhere and then "expression"

Comment: @SubharanjanSahoo  In that case, try `substr(regmatches(str, regexpr("expression", str)), 1, 3)#
[1] "exp"`  Or may be `grep(substr("expression", 1, 3),str, value = TRUE) 
[1] "exp"`

Comment: Is there anyway I can match "expression" with "exp" without doing  substr()? substr() is not the solution because I can not apply this to anything other then "expression"as this is hard coded. Please suggest if there is any other way to directly match. Thanks again.